# Как округлить число до десятков тысяч?

Tags: python

Предположим у нас есть число 155467. Необходимо округлить его до десятков тысяч, то бишь получить число 160000. Есть ли в Python какой-то деликатный метод округления числа до разрядов, не прибегая к преобразованию в строковый тип и замены разрядов на нолики....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Зачем строковый тип, если есть `round`:

```
x = 155_467
n = 10_000
print(n * round(x/n))
# 160000
```

Делим, округляем, обратно домножаем.

Answer (score 2):

Есть вот такой быстрый способ округления в большую сторону:

```py
x = 155467

x -= x % -10000
print(x)
```

***stdout:***

```py
160000
```

Comment: Но это же не настоящее округление, это округление в верхнюю сторону. Даже 150001 до 160000 "округляет".

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, Вы правы. Указал это в ответе, чтобы не вводить в заблуждение

Comment: **Дисклеймер**: Округление происходит только в большую сторону. Удалил бы ответ, но не могу, так как он принят автором.

Comment: Спасибо, мне и так подошло.

Answer (score 2):

Не усложняйте себе жизнь изобретением велосипеда round(n, -4)